Matched Filtering
How is matched filtering done in digital systems? Is the signal normalized after the filtering. Cause the matched filter output depends on the number of samples you are using to sample the signal.

This question is similar to: Understanding the Matched Filter, as well as detailed in many places on the web, YouTube etc. Please be more specific what it is that still confuses you about any of these explanations, otherwise this question is too broad and unclear where to start.
